# Div absolute position relative to static elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element which I'm using as a pop-over search field which I want to have appear under the element which is being filtered. However, it seems that I cannot use the style.bottom and style.left of the  element I want the field to be relative to as this element is static.

Example is here: http://www.is-epic.co.uk/example/example.html

Clicking the Header 2 link will have the input box appear, in the top-left corner of the table. I would like it to appear roughly where Data 1.2 is. How do I achieve this?

*(Code in example.html is on one page, in live dev CSS and JS are in separate files)*

Comment: Note: you are using the XHTML1.1 doctype. That version is for XML applications but you are serving the page as HTML. You should change it to HTML4.01 doctype, or maybe HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works in FF and Google-Chrome

```
var head = document.getElementById("header_2");
var filter = document.getElementById("search_filter");

filter.style.display = "";
filter.style.left = head.offsetLeft + 'px';
filter.style.top = head.offsetTop + head.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

it should work with IE as well..

*i used variables filter and head to cut down on typing :)*

Answer (score 3):

Set the element you wish to position the other element with respect to to `position: relative`.

This will make it the containing block for any descendants that are `position: absolute` (unless an element between the two is also `position: not static`).

Comment: This does not work, because #search_filter is *not* a descendant of #header_2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for `header_2` both `style.left` and `style.bottom` are 0, so that

```
document.getElementById("search_filter").style.left =
     document.getElementById("header_2").style.left;
document.getElementById("search_filter").style.top =
     document.getElementById("header_2").style.bottom;
```

is equivalent to

```
document.getElementById("search_filter").style.left = 0;
document.getElementById("search_filter").style.top = 0;
```

which is exactly what happens. You have to find out `header_2`'s *actual* position, e.g. using jQuery.